# How to traverse the GCC AST nodes?

Tags: c, gcc, ast

I have looked into AST representations here [http://icps.u-strasbg.fr/~pop/gcc-ast.html](http://icps.u-strasbg.fr/%7Epop/gcc-ast.html) and I would like to know how I can programmatically access this tree/traverse the nodes of my source.c file?
Pseudocode from the link:

```
char * fnName = IDENTIFIER_POINTER (DECL_NAME (fnDecl));
tree fnBody = DECL_SAVED_TREE (fnDecl);
```